How can I repair an underground PVC gutter pipe?
I was doing some planting using an auger to dig holes. Since there was already a large shrub here I didn't think anything would be there. It was too late when I saw something green.
I assume it is a drain pipe for the gutters (which you can see at the top right of the photo).
How can I repair this?



UPDATE:
Septic is on the other side of the house and the pipe is dry inside.
The question is: what is the quickest, easiest and cheapest repair?
The options I see are: cut section and use a coupler, some kind of PVC agent to apply to the crack, wrap some flashing tape or call someone to raplce the whole thing ($$$)
thanks
SOLVED!
Thanks to  @MonkeyZeus and  @Milwrdfan I combined the two processes and fixed it.
thanks




Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to join PVC pipe? What about that's confusing? Have you looked into the rest of the circuit to see what's what? Step one is usually gathering information, of which we have little here. Move some dirt and update your photos. Determine whether the joints are cemented or just slip-fit.

Figure out without assuming if it's the gutter pipe, or if you've managed to find the sewer line/septic pipe, which are also often done in that exact sort of green PVC. The latter would be a bit more serious.

To confirm it's just a gutter line, run some water into the gutter and see if it comes out through the broken section.
If it is just a gutter drain line, the easiest would be to excavate around the damage, cut the damaged section out, and use a replacement piece of pipe along with a couple Fernco (or other similar brand) couplings rated for ground contact (they may all be, I'm not sure) to make the repair.  It's not pressurized or sewage, so using some rubber couplings seems to be the easiest to handle the downspout drainage.  Even if it doesn't completely seal, a slight drip from the coupling won't be any problem there underground.

I believe green PCV is "Schedule 35" which has a different wall thickness than the white Schedule 40 seen inside your home.
You will need these materials:

Two 4" slip couplings
A short section of new Schedule 35 4" PVC
PVC primer and cement

At minimum, you will need these tools:

A hacksaw or sawzall
A shovel

You will need to perform this work:

Dig out enough dirt to reveal the extent of the damage and provide enough working space
Cut out broken PVC section
Wash and dry 12" of the old pipe ends
Cut new PVC to length
Apply slip coupling to both ends
Put new PVC in place
Follow the procedure for priming and cementing slip couplings into place

Albeit you're probably fine without gluing the couplings into place. A dab or line of silicone would likely suffice just so you can securely bury the pipe


Re-bury the pipe


Note that step 1 involves digging out an obnoxiously large amount below the pipe, as well, to give working room to cut the pipe and put the slip joints & new section of pipe in. It's just a royal pain...

@MonkeyZeus  One of the improvement stores sells SDR.  Sound about right? "PVC D 3034 Sewer Main Pipe is for sewer and storm drainage purposes only. Used in gravity fed waste elimination systems, it is highly resistant to chemicals commonly found in sewage and industrial waste. Also known as SDR 35, PVC D 3034 Sewer Main Pipe is available in two joining methods: gasketed or solvent weld. PVC D 3034 Sewer Main Pipe extends from the end of the building drain and conveys the discharge to a sewer or other point of disposal."

@Marinaio Yep! SDR 35 is schedule 35

Unfortunately, you'll probably have to go to an online store for the repair couplings, unless you have a good plumbing supply shop in your area.
